# unable to compile glsl program caused by stdafx.h

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I was trying to compile a GLSL program, but it shows this error

```
warning C4627: '#include "Angel.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you  
forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source
```

But actually I already include the stdafx.h and I created the project using the Visual Studio 2012 with the precompiled header

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Angel.h"
const int NumPoints = 5000;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

void
init( void )
{
    vec2 points[NumPoints];
    ...
```

Comment: Did you just have 1 single cpp file? Or do you have #include "stdafx.h" at the top of every single cpp file in your project?

Comment: Are you trying to compile a GLSL shader using the Visual C++ compiler?

Comment: Look at this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7fz9ckx.aspx

Comment: i just use 1 cpp file, and I;m trying to compile the GLSL shader using the visual c++ compiler

Comment: @user2629285 there's no error in that log. But anyways, the glsl shader itself can not be compiled with VisualC++ that's a C++ compiler not a glsl compiler (that's its own language). You can only compile glsl shaders with the `glCompileShader` function after providing the sourcecode  to `glShaderSource`. It seems like you really need to read either a book or a very extensive tutorial. You have a lot of misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to go to the project property page  -> C/C++ -> Precompiled headers -> turn the `Precompiled Header` from `Use(/Yu)` to `Not using precompiled headers`.

Comment: i've changed the setting but it's still error, but the error changed, i've written the new error

Comment: @user2629285 Wouldn't it be cool if you marked this one as answered and linked in a new question with an edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is really funny. GLSL cannot, by any means, be compiled with C/C++ compiler - GLSL compiler built into a OpenGL driver and it's internals isn't exposed. You have to provide source code (in text form) to OpenGL, it will compile it every time itself.